# Binary string play

Tags: python, string, list, recursion, binary

Problem :

We are given a series of Binary Strings. The first term in this series is 0. Hence, T1 = '0'.
To find the string at any given Ti, we look at Ti - 1 and replace all occurances of '0' with '01' and '1' with '10'.
You are given two integers N and X, your job is to find TN and return its Xth index.
Note: Ti are 1-indexed.

> Input Format:
>
> First line of input contains an integer T, representing the number of
> test cases. The next T lines contains two space separated integers, N
> and X.

> Output Format:
>
> Print the Xth index in Nth row

Sample Input:

```
1
4 5
```

Sample Output:

```
1
```

Explanation:

```
T1: '0'
T2: '01'
T3: '0110'
T4: '01101001'
```

The 5th element in T4 is '1'.

I tried below solution but getting time limit exceed for n value greater than 25.how to handle large test cases ?

```py
from sys import stdin , setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit(10**8)
t = int(input())

def temp(s,n):
    if n==0:
        return s
    ans = ''
    d = {
        '0':'01',
        '1':'10'
    }
    for ele in s:
        ans+=d[ele]
        
    return temp(ans,n-1)
   
while t:
    n,x = [int(x) for x in stdin.readline().strip().split()] 
    s = '0'
    res = temp(s,n)
    print(res[x-1])
    
    t-=1
```

Comment: " advise better way to handle these kind of problems" is too general. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with *I tried below solution but getting TLE in each run.* What do you mean with TLE?

Comment: This is a very interesting puzzle. One key aspect of the puzzle, however, which seems to form a pattern and effectively may remove the need for recursion from the solution, is that the idea of (x: 'a value which is a power of two' (for example '0'), and that there is only one possible y value, and that this x value when expanded in the next iteration forms x + y whilst the y value forms y + x) applies to all substrings which have a length which is a power of 2. This pattern will likely not remove the need for recursion but will allow for a much faster algorithm with a lower recursion depth.

Comment: @Claudio, TLE - time limit exceeded

Comment: Proof: x=0, y=1; x -> x+y = 01, y -> y+x = 10 (for 1 bit substrings)

Comment: x=01, y=10; x -> x+y = 0110, y -> y+x = 1001 (for 2 bit substrings taken in order)

Comment: x=0110, y=1001; x -> x+y = 01101001, y -> y+x = 10010110

Comment: x=01101001, y=10010110; x -> x+y = 0110100110010110, y -> y+x = 1001011001101001

Comment: And so. You get the idea: rather that applying the rule of 0->01 and 1->10 to each bit in the string, and continuing till you get the desired row, you can find a simplification by getting to a specific row and and halving it's length, giving you your new x and y to work with which will flower out into a different sequence skipping through some rows till you get the row you need.

Comment: Additionally, if the index you want is less than half the length of the row you want it from, you can get that index from the smallest row it exists in and it will be the same index as the one you need because all values in a row are the same and in the same position in the coming rows

Comment: Hope that helps, I don't think I can solve because I've never used stdin and am new to python but

Comment: In the comment 3 places above this one (the "And so on" one) I described the simplification incorrectly. Rather that applying the rule of 0->01 and 1->10 to each bit in the string, and continuing till you get the desired row, you can find a simplification by taking the row before and and halving it's length, giving you your new x and y to work use for the row the computer is on. I was wrong, it won't reduce recursion depth but it will definitely increase the speed of the algorithm and hopefully remove the threat of TLE with large rows and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can use iteration (`for` loop) rather than recursion:

```py
# Iterative function to get T(i)
def T(i): # Define function
    l = '0' # Variable that holds the last value in the sequence
    for _ in range(i-1): # Iterate i-1 times
        d = {'0': '01', '1': '10'} # Just like in your code
        l = ''.join(map(d.get, l)) # Equivalent to ''.join(d[c] for c in l)
    return l # Return the last value

r = int(input()) # Number of test cases
while r: # Just like in your code
    n, x = map(int, input().split()) # Get n and x as input, and convert to integer
    print(T(n)[x-1]) # Get T(n) and get the xth index
    r -= 1 # Decrement r by 1
```

Input:

```
1
4 5
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: The  Thonnu ,Thanks for helping. I tried your code still getting TLE for value of n >= 25

Comment: @code_dominar - I can't reproduce that. It works fine for me. What input did you test it with?

Comment: @ The Thonnu, I tried for n=30 and x=20

Answer (score 0):

There is a pattern for the elements generated.

```
0
01
0110
01101001
0110100110010110
01101001100101101001011001101001
0110100110010110100101100110100110010110011010010110100110010110
```

That pattern is `nextElement` is `previousElement + flipallbits(previousElement)`.
And try to form a recurrence relation to find the bit in a particular index.

So say if an index say 4, its the flipped operation of index 0.

Say if an index say 5, its the flipped operation of index 1. which inturn is a
flipped operation of index 0.

So you have remove the highest power of 2 from the index and then flip the bit and if index is 0 return 0.

```
x = 3
def findElement(x):
    if(x == 0):
        return False
    power = 1
    while (power*2) <= x:
        power *= 2
    return not findElement(x - power)
print(int(findElement(x)))
```

There is no need for n in this implementation.
Another option is just count, the number of ones in the binary representation of index x and the check if its even. if its even return 0 else 1.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to see the pattern, where for odd to even number transiiton it is just previous string + reverse of it whereas for even to odd transition it is previous string + complement of value of previous string

here is code

```
def function(n, x):
    tmp = ['0']
    if n==0:
        if x>len(tmp)-1:
            return -1
        elif x<=len(tmp)-1:
            return tmp[x]
    for i in range(1, n):
        if not i%2:
            tmp = tmp + tmp[::-1]
        else:
            tmp = tmp + ['0' if i=='1' else '1' for i in tmp]
    if x<=len(tmp)-1:
        return tmp[x]
    return -1
```

`-1` if index out of range.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def find_character(N, X):
    if N == 1:
        return "0" if X == 1 else "1"
    
    mid = 2**(N-1)
    if X <= mid:
        return find_character(N-1, X)
    else:
        return "1" if find_character(N-1, X-mid) == "0" else "0"

# Taking input
T = int(input())

for _ in range(T):
    N, X = map(int, input().split())

    # Calling the function
    result = find_character(N, X)
    print(result)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

def find_character(N, X):
if N == 1:
return "0" if X == 1 else "1"

```
mid = 2**(N-1)
if X <= mid:
    return find_character(N-1, X)
else:
    return "1" if find_character(N-1, X-mid) == "0" else "0"
```

T = int(input())

for _ in range(T):
N, X = map(int, input().split())
result = find_character(N, X)
print(result)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).